# Count sql results and display with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to retrieve a list of referring urls from a MySQL table (column `referrer`), count urls that appear more than once and list the urls and the count in descending order. I cant work it out!!

```
$ref=$icdb->get_row("SELECT count(1) AS frequency, referrer FROM url_log WHERE u = '".$dom."'GROUP BY referrer ORDER BY frequency DESC");

foreach ($ref as $details) {
echo $details['referrer']."</td><td>".$details['frequency']."</td>";
}
```

Comment: Is the problem you are having simply that you are not excluding items with count of 1 from result set?

Comment: this sentence's syntax doesn't really points towards thinking that he wishes to exclude the rows with count one. @Ryerye can you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter out the items with a count of one, you might consider use of `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS frequency, referrer
FROM url_log
WHERE u = ?
GROUP BY referrer
HAVING frequency > 1
ORDER BY frequency DESC
```

In essence the `HAVING` clause allows you to provide additional filtering conditions after initial result set specified by main query with `WHERE` clause is calculated. Probably the most common usage of this feature is to specify filtering conditions on aggregation fields.

Comment: How do I display the array? This doesn't work:

`foreach ($ref as $details) {
   echo $details['referrer']."</td><td>".$details['frequency']."</td>";
}`

Comment: @ryerye Hard to say, as I have no idea what `$ref` holds since you seem to be using some custom DB class. Why not add `var_dump($ref)` results to your original question.

Comment: @ryerye Also, are you sure `$ref` holds the entire result set?  It would seem odd to have a method named `get_row` that returned all rows in a result set.

Comment: See my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489658/count-duplicates-in-sql-results-and-display-with-php/21489745
:)