# Count duplicates in sql results and display with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve a list of referring urls from a MySQL table (column `referrer`).
The `referrer` column contain the same URL more than once, in which I want to count and print how many times the URL appears. Then print the counts in descending order.

I've got the following code, but obviously is wrong somewhere

```
$ref=$icdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(referrer) AS frequency, referrer FROM url_log WHERE u = '".$dom."' GROUP BY referrer ORDER BY frequency DESC");


foreach ($ref as $details) {
   echo "<td>".$details['referrer']."</td><td>".$details['frequency']."</td>";
}
```

I have exported some of the sql data as an array:

```
$url_log = array(
  array('id' => '681','url_id' => '69','options' => '','created_day' => '20140128','created' => '1390945235','deleted' => '0','u' => 'rch.metwitter','referrer' => 'http://www.domain.com/','ipaddr' => '121.223.91.20','browser' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'),
  array('id' => '685','url_id' => '69','options' => '','created_day' => '20140130','created' => '1391115029','deleted' => '0','u' => 'rch.metwitter','referrer' => 'http://www.domain.com/?page=custom&id=69','ipaddr' => '121.223.91.20','browser' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'),
  array('id' => '686','url_id' => '69','options' => '','created_day' => '20140130','created' => '1391116005','deleted' => '0','u' => 'rch.metwitter','referrer' => 'http://www.domain.com/','ipaddr' => '121.223.91.20','browser' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko')
);
```

The foreach statement gives me:

3 3 h h

Comment: not obvious to me :-(

Comment: would be better to help us , provide some sample data . or fiddle

Comment: See the above edit @echo_Me

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with COUNT(1).
I suggest changing it to COUNT(referrer).

Comment: I get the following:
3 3 h h

Comment: i cant find any other mistake inyour code.Your problem  is somewhere else.